# Solving $X=\frac{b-a}{d+e}$, $Y=2\sin(\frac{X}2)\left(\frac{c}{X}+f\right)$, $Z=2\sin(\frac{X}2)\left(\frac{a}{X}+d\right)$ for $a$, $b$, $c$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Let's assume we know the following:

$$a = 1,\quad b = 4,\quad c = 7,\quad d = 2,\quad e = 2,\quad f = 9$$

With these six variables, we can apply some formulas and solve for $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ as follows:

$$\begin{align}
X &= \frac{b - a}{d + e} \\[1em]
Y &= 2\sin\left(\frac{X}2\right)\left(\frac{c}{X} + f\right) \\[1em]
Z &= 2\sin\left(\frac{X}2\right)\left(\frac{a}{X} + d\right)
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
X &= 0.75 \\
Y &= 13.42999273315508 \\
Z &= 2.4418168605736503
\end{align}$$

Now, let's flip things around and assume that we're **given** the values of $X$, $Y$, and $Z$, **as well as** $d$, $e$, and $f$.

I haven't taken a math course in 30 years.  How would we solve for the values of $a$, $b$, and $c$?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: This would turn it into a system of linear equations. So many options of methods!

Comment: Thank you.  Would you be able to help me "structure" what the matrix (or matrices) might look like? (so that I can then encode it using a statistical analysis library)

Comment: With $\sin u$ in there so often, I'm uncertain we can call these a "linear" system of equations. There's a whole lot of $\arcsin u$ needed here.

Comment: If $x$ is known then no $\arcsin$ is needed, as OP says by supposition.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Good point. So $2\sin(X/2)$ is just a constant.

Comment: If you know a,b,c,d,e,f, then you can’t call them ’variables’. They are **constants**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked about matrices, but given the fact that $X$ is known, and each equation has only one or two unknowns, you don't need anything like matrices. Let $S=2\sin (X/2)$. Then, rearranging to get the unknowns alone, your equations become:

$$-a+b= X(d+e)$$

$$c = X\left(\frac YS -f\right)$$

$$a = X\left(\frac ZS -d\right)$$

And by quick substitution,

$$b = X\left(\frac ZS +e\right)$$